# Formatter exception deserializing Agatha request

Tags: wcf, iis, datacontractserializer

I've been scratching my head with this one off and on for a couple of
days now and I'm hoping someone can offer some insight. First, the
exception...

> An exception was returned by an activity: The formatter threw an
>   exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error
>   while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:requests.
>   The InnerException message was 'Error in line 1 position 837. Element
>   'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Agatha.Common.Request'
>   contains data from a type that maps to the name 'http://
>   schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/
>   MyCompany.MyProduct.Services.Contracts.Customers:ReadAllCustomersRequest'.
>   The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name.
>   Consider using a DataContractResolver or add the type corresponding to
>   'ReadAllCustomersRequest' to the list of known types - for example, by
>   using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding it to the list of
>   known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'. Please see
>   InnerException for more details.

Okay, that's fair. Seems like the serializer isn't aware that my type
(ReadAllCustomersRequest) inherits from Agatha's Request. Odd, since
Agatha should be dealing with that during the config. My service layer
config looks like this...

```
// NOTE: A Unity container (re: the container variable) is built upelsewhere.

var agathaServiceConfiguration = new ServiceLayerConfiguration(new Container(container));
agathaServiceConfiguration.AddRequestHandlerAssembly(typeof(ReadAllCustomersHandler).Assembly);
agathaServiceConfiguration.AddRequestAndResponseAssembly(typeof(ReadAllCustomersRequest).Assembly);
agathaServiceConfiguration.Initialize();
```

Note that my handler types are in the same assembly as the this code
(MyCompany.MyProduct.Services). My request and response types,
however, are in a different assembly
(MyCompany.MyProduct.Services.Contracts). No big deal. After all, I
basically copied Brion's "Hello World" (and referenced the examples in
the Agatha source).

The thing is that this all works just fine. No errors whatsoever...
when run locally (Win7/VS2010/Cassini). If I push the server-side
shebang out to an IIS 7.5 site, however, I start getting the exception
above. Same compiled assemblies. Same config file. Different result.
Oh, IIS... how I love thee.

I very much doubt this is an Agatha problem since, as I said, it runs
just fine locally. I'm just wondering if anyone has any clue as to why
it fails when I drop it out to a remote server. I'm probably missing
something very, very obvious.

Oh, and for what it's worth, the IIS 7.5 site is hosting non-Agatha
(boo!) services just fine. My mex endpoints are enumerated just fine,
too. Oh, and Elmah records nothing server-side. Everything's normal
until I send a request from the client.

So, there's *something* about my deployment that's bonked, but it's
got me stumped. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

My deployment was bonked and my Global.asax wasn't deployed correctly. *Sigh...*